# Flutter `pubspec.lock` Is Not Updating As Per Versions In `pubspec.yaml` After `flutter pub get`

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, sdk

I was working on a project that have the `Android Version 31 SDK` then for testing purpose, I installed a package from `pub.dev` in `pubspec.yaml` that require `Android Version 33 SDK` that I don't want to upgrade so I change the back version again in `pubspec.yaml` and deleted `pubspec.lock` then run `flutter pub get` but from here it started showing me error as "... Some of the Plugins needs `Android Version 33 SDK` ..."

Now my project is totally stuck and can Run & Build due to this error. For the resetting purpose, I did the following...

1. Deleted `pubspec.lock` then run `flutter pub get`.
2. Run `flutter pub cache repair`  then run `flutter pub get`
3. Run `flutter pub cache clean` then run `flutter pub get`
4. Run "Invalidates Caches..." in Android Studio then run `flutter pub get`
5. In Android Studio go to Tools -> SDK Manager -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> Uninstall Android API 33 then run `flutter pub get`
6. In Android Studio go to Tools -> SDK Manager -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> Uninstall Android Build Tool API 33 then run `flutter pub get`
7. Deleted build and .dart Folders then run `flutter pub get`
8. Run `flutter clean` then run `flutter pub get`

**What To Do Now To Revert My Project At `Android Version 31 SDK`...???**

### Note:

Doing everything as shared earlier, I open my `pubspec.lock` and seeing every-time new version of my installed package that require `Android Version 33 SDK` even `pubspec.yaml` is showing my old version of installed package means they both are not same in versions.

### Flutter Doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.5, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-arm, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 2.10.5 at /Users/novusaltairkarachi/Documents/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 5464c5bac7 (5 months ago), 2022-04-18 09:55:37 -0700
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/novusaltairkarachi/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 105.0.5195.125

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
Process finished with exit code 0
```

More Info As Requested, Rest Information Is Shared In Upper "flutter doctor" Result:

```
compileSdkVersion 31
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 31
```

Answer (score -1):

Please state the following:

1. Your target sdk version
2. Compile sdk version
3. Sdk build tools version
4. Sdk command line tools versions

And have tried a simple flutter clean? Also try invalidate caches and restar. By any chance have you run flutter pub upgrade?

Comment: Whenever need more information about the question please post it as comment not as answer.

Comment: Question is updated as requested with more info... Run everything as shared in question. Never run `flutter pub upgrade` ever.